# Transfers from asset_pallet with generated pallet account

Tags: assets

I want to use the Asset pallet from another custom pallet. The goal is to use the custom pallet account and transfers the assets of this account to another one using this function: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.18/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L692

But how do we handle the Origin ( https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.18/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L693 ) as we don't have the possibility to sign it ( because it use generated pallet account like treasury does) ?

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest is this.
Don't tightly couple your pallet to `pallet-assets`. Instead, put an associated type in your pallet's config with a [Transfer](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungibles/trait.Transfer.html) trait bound (assets pallet implements it). Then, you can use the [transfer](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungibles/trait.Transfer.html#tymethod.transfer) method from that trait, which does not require origin.